# Tailwind.css - a "fixed" element is out the parent "container" element

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, tailwind-css, css-position

I'm coming to you, requesting your gentle help.

I have a fixed element that is displaying outside the container parent element on big screen...Basically, it is "fixed" from the view port point of view and not from the parent relative element.

[image]

How can I fix it ?
[image]

Thank you for your help !

If you need any additional information, please let me know
Best regards,

Comment: Fixed is to the viewport. Did you mean to use sticky?

Answer (score 1):

yes, that's what fixed elements do (i.e. they are at a fixed position in the viewport/window). Use `position: absolute` to position an element relatively to its parent. And apply `position: relative` to the parent in this case.

Comment: Thank you ... while it is true, the "absolute" position is not what I am looking for since then the fixed element is available only at the bottom of the whole container...I need it available all the time when scrolling..

So - I need a fixed position ... with a constraint on the width as per the parent container...

Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I was looking for...

```
<!-- Parent -->    
<div class="relative container max-w-screen-xl bg-slate-200 pb-4">
  <!-- Child - fixed element -->
  <div class="fixed w-full max-w-screen-xl bottom-[10%] flex flex-row justify-end pr-16"></div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help !
Best regards,
LN